# How to refer to unnamed object in R

Tags: r

I want to perform a simple task in R. I want to call a method on an object which has not been assigned to any variable yet.
Like this:

```
a <- c(5, 2, 11, 3)
b <- order(a, decreasing = TRUE)[1:floor(0.1 * length(.))]
```

So I guess, I would like to to find, what to pass to length function here. I know that I can perform it like this:

```
a <- c(5, 2, 11, 3)
b <- order(a, decreasing = TRUE)
b <- b[1:floor(0.1 * length(b))]
```

But I wanted to make it like I wrote above.

Comment: Since you are ordering,  wouldn't the `length` be same as `a`? So you can do `order(a, decreasing = TRUE)[1:floor(0.1 * length(a))]`

Comment: This is what pipes for: `library(magrittr) ; order(a, decreasing = TRUE) %>% .[1:floor(0.1 * length(.))]`

Answer (score 1):

There is as far as i know, no implemented way that will achieve higher efficiency than the base code

```
a <- c(5, 2, 11, 3)
b <- order(a, decreasing = TRUE)
b[1:floor(0.1 * length(b))]
```

However one can achieve something similar to what you are asking, using either the `magrittr`, the `dplyr` or similar packages, which allow for piping calls. This would look similar to

```
a <- c(5, 2, 11, 3)
c <- a %>% order(., decreasing = TRUE) %>% .[1:floor(0.1 * length(.))]
identical(b[1:floor(0.1 * length(b))],c)
[1] TRUE
```